# subtracting 2 date columns in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following pandas dataframe

[image]

I want to subtract date_of_birth from date_of_death to make a new column, "years_lived" to contain the years lived. I tried all 3 ways below (individually of course)

```
df['years_lived'] = (df['date_of_death'] - df['date_of_birth']).dt.days
df['years_lived'] = df['date_of_death'].sub(df['date_of_birth'], axis=0)
df['years_lived'] = df['date_of_death'] - df['date_of_birth']
```

but I got a TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'

Comment: need minimal and reproducible example code not image https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
df['years_lived'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_of_death']) - pd.to_datetime(df['date_of_birth'])
```

Answer (score 0):

pd.to_datetime will convert your dates into datetime and you can subtract one from the other.

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert str represenation of dates to dates before subracting.

```
df['years_lived'] = (df['date_of_death'].astype(dt.timedelta) - df['date_of_birth'].astype(dt.timedelta)).dt.days
```

or

if deosn't work convert before and then subract

```
df['date_of_death'] = pd.to_numeric(df['date_of_death'], errors='coerce').fillna(0).astype(int)
df['date_of_birth'] =  pd.to_numeric(df['date_of_birth'], errors='coerce').fillna(0).astype(int)
df['years_lived'] = (df['date_of_death'] - df['date_of_birth']).dt.days
```